# (Solved) TwilioCall Method works in Execute Anonymous Window but fails to fire in Apex

Tags: apex, callout, url, twilio

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looking at the logs it looks like when the case is created none of the variables are passed and nothing is sent to twilio - for the class above. The sms that is triggered at the same time works fine. –

The code below works perfectly in Execute Anonymous Window

```
String account = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
String token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);

Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
'To'   => '+xxxxxxxxx',
'From' => '+xxxxxxxxxx',                
 by Twilio
'Url' => 'https://pink-dog-6501.twil.io/assets/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3'
};

TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
```

However when I place it in Apex below nothing fires. As far as I can tell I followed the docs correctly and it should work

```
public class sendCaseCall {

   @Future(callout = true)
   public static void callPhoneService(Set<ID> caseIDs)
   {
        List<Case> newCases = [Select Id, ContactId, ContactMobile, CaseNumber, Subject 
                               from Case 
                               Where ID in :caseIDs] ;

        for (Case c : newCases){
            String account = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            String token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);

            Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
                'To'   => '+xxxxxxxxx',
                'From' => '+xxxxxxxxxx',                
                'Url' => 'https://pink-dog-6501.twil.io/assets/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3'
            };

            TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
            Task newTask = new Task();
            newTask.WhatId = c.id;
            newTask.WhoId = c.ContactId;
            newTask.Subject = 'Sent Case Creation Call';
            newTask.priority= 'High' ;
            newTask.status = 'Completed';
            newTask.description = string.valueOf('Call Sent') ;
            newTask.ActivityDate = System.today() ;
            insert newtask;
        }
    }
}
```

I have something very similar that sends an sms when a new case is created and that works perfectly

Comment: how is it "not working" ? any debugging?

Comment: Looking at the logs it looks like when the case is created none of the variables are passed and nothing is sent to twilio - for the class above. The sms that is triggered at the same time works fine.

Comment: please make sure you include this in your post, thanks =)

Comment: Ok, I updated the post as suggested.

Comment: A suggestion, don't make callouts from within a for loop as you will likely hit the max callout limit `A single Apex transaction can make a maximum of 100 callouts to an HTTP request or an API call.`

Comment: Good Point Bob, I will work on that change for sure.

Comment: I still don't have not figured out why I can't make the Twilio call to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while and I have working method. I am using a for loop so I may have issues with that, If you have an idea how to fix that feel free to let me know.

So here is the "final" solution:

```
public class SendCallTriggered {

@InvocableMethod
public static void callPhoneService(List<ID> caseIDs) {
    List<Case> SelectCase = [Select Id, ContactPhone from Case Where ID in :caseIDs] ;
for (Case c : SelectCase){
   Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
'To'   => c.ContactPhone,
'From' => '+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',              
'Url' => 'https://pink-dog-6501.twil.io/assets/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3'
};

    DoCallout(params);      
 }
  }

@future(callout=true)

private static void DoCallout(Map<String, String> params){
String account = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
String token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);
TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
    system.debug('TwilioCAL' + call);
}
}
```

Best part is I can use use Process builder to fire this code, so happy. I have not built code for handling number of rings to allow, or for voicemail. That will be next